# What are *C*, *E* and *S* properties in message call return object?

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation, contract-debugging, bignumber

(JS)

```
 var contract = web3.eth.contract(abiDefinition).at(address);
     contract.test(value, gotResult);
     function gotResult(error, result) {
            if(!error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
            else {
                console.log(result);
            }                               
    }
```

(SOL)

```
 contract A {
     function test(uint8 x) constant returns(uint8) {
         return x + 10;
     }
  }
```

(BROWSER)

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`result` is a **[BigNumber](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js) object** that is stringified to something like `{ [String: '5'] s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 5 ] }`.  You can use BigNumber methods, like `result.toNumber()` to see it better.

When integers are involved, web3.js uses BigNumber because native Javascript numbers are not large enough.

It's out of scope here to go into the internals of a general external library like BigNumber.

The main thing that helps is to **recognize that when you get an object that looks like it, is that it's probably a BigNumber** and you can call methods on it, as well as perform other additional BigNumber operations (without needing to know its internals).

Comment: What does S, C, E stand for?

Comment: @quantumpotato According to the BigNumber [repo](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/), S stands for sign, E for exponent and C for coefficient (or significand).