# Having trouble interacting with a simple contract

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, contract-invocation, struct

I'm a beginner trying to interact with a simple contract via web3, and I'm having some problems that I can't figure out.

I've written a basic contract with a struct and two functions. This is basically copied from here: [Returning a struct and reading via Web3](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3609/returning-a-struct-and-reading-via-web3/3614#3614)

```
contract MyContract {
    struct MyStruct {
        address a;
        uint b;
    }

    MyStruct[] public MyStructs;

    function getStruct(uint index) public constant returns (address, uint) {
        return (MyStructs[index].a, MyStructs[index].b);
    }

    function addStruct(address _a, uint _b) public returns (uint){
        MyStruct memory a = MyStruct(_a, _b);
        MyStructs.length++;
        MyStructs.push(a);
        return MyStructs.length;
    }
}
```

I have two test functions that I'm invoking using truffle's test feature. These are basically copied from http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/javascript-tests

```
var MyContract = artifacts.require("MyContract");


contract('MyContract', function() {
  it("should create a stuct", function() {
    return MyContract.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      return instance.addStruct.call(0xf17f52151EbEF6C7334FAD080c5704D77216b732, 1000);
    }).then(function(length) {
       console.log(length);
       assert.equal(length, 1, "length is not 1");

    });
  });

  it("get the struct that was previously created", function() {
    return MyContract.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      return instance.getStruct.call(0);
    }).then(function(values) {
      console.log(values);
      assert.equal(values, (0xf17f52151EbEF6C7334FAD080c5704D77216b732, 1000));
    });
  });
});
```

When I run this, I get the following:

```
  Contract: MyContract { [String: '2'] s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 2 ] }
    1) should create a stuct
    > No events were emitted
    2) get the struct that was previously created
    > No events were emitted


  0 passing (190ms)   2 failing

  1) Contract: MyContract should create a stuct:
     AssertionError: length is not 1: expected { Object (s, e, ...) } to equal 1
      at test/mycontract.js:10:15
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)

  2) Contract: MyContract get the struct that was previously created:
     Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: {"id":21,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}
      at Object.InvalidResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:41483:16)
      at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:330353:36
      at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:326008:9
      at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:329052:7)
      at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:176427:18)
      at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:176717:12)
      at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:176872:12)
      at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:176832:24)
```

In other words, when it gets to console.log(length), which should be the response of the addStruct function, it is instead getting `{ [String: '2'] s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 2 ] }`, and then getStruct errors out with `Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: {"id":21,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}`

Any idea why this is happening? Both of these things mean nothing to me, so I don't even know what to Google. I've looked at the Truffle and Solidity documentation, and as far as I can tell, I am doing everything correctly.

Perhaps unrelated, but I'm including just in case it isn't --
previously, I had deployed this to Ganache successfully and was playing around in the browser console. I was able to call web3.eth.contract(abi) and get what appears to be the correct response, but when I added the address as an argument, it refused to give me anything except "invalid address." I confirmed in the web3 and ganache documentation that I was doing it right about 10 times, so I'm thinking that maybe something else is wrong. Or maybe not -- feel free to ignore this part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first scenario, your result is **BigNumber**, so you just need to add `.toNumber()` to `length`:

```
  it("should create a stuct", function() {
    return MyContract.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      return instance.addStruct.call(0xf17f52151EbEF6C7334FAD080c5704D77216b732, 1000);
    }).then(function(length) {
       console.log(length.toNumber());
       assert.equal(length.toNumber(), 1, "length is not 1");
    });
  });
```

Related: [What are *C*, *E* and *S* properties in message call return object?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/7657/9938)

---

In second scenario I reworked your test a little bit:

```
it("get the struct that was previously created", function() {
    return MyContract.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      instance.addStruct.sendTransaction("0xf17f52151ebef6c7334fad080c5704d77216b732", 1000);
      return instance.getStruct.call(1);
    }).then(function(values) {
      console.log(values[0].toString(), values[1].toNumber());
      assert.equal(values[0].toString(), "0xf17f52151ebef6c7334fad080c5704d77216b732", 'blah-blah');
      assert.equal(values[1].toNumber(), 1000, 'blah-blah');
    });
  });
```

---

We will execute `sendTransaction` to actually add new struct to array. Then we will `call` it and returned array will be read with `.toString()` and `.toNumber()` to normalize output.

---

*It is also good to note that if we `call` `getStruct` with 0 it returns `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 0`.*

### And the fix is:

```
function addStruct(address _a, uint _b) public returns (uint){
    MyStruct memory a = MyStruct(_a, _b);
    MyStructs.push(a);
    // delete this line (MyStructs.length++;)
    return MyStructs.length;
}
```

After this edit you can change `call` value from 0 back to 1 here:

```
return instance.getStruct.call(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

@roman-frolov nailed the first issue.

For the second issue, I believe the problem is that you used `call` instead of `sendTransaction` when you invoked `addStruct`. Calls don't actually send transactions out to the network; they just run the function locally and then discard the side effects. So no struct was actually added to `MyStructs`. The subsequent call to `getStruct` will fail because it uses an invalid index into the array. (It tries index 0, but the array length is still 0.)