# Contract testing works in solidity but fails in truffle - testrpc

Tags: truffle, testrpc

I have a contract like this:
PublishService.sol, the strings.sol is taken from [here](https://github.com/Arachnid/solidity-stringutils/blob/master/strings.sol).

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

import "./strings.sol";
contract PublishService
{

using strings for *;
struct ServiceListStruct {
string _cloudID;
address _gatewayID;
string _serviceProducerID;
string _serviceProducerMetadata;
string _serviceConsumerMetaAttr;
}
ServiceListStruct[] BCServiceList;

function countEntries() public returns (uint)
{
    return BCServiceList.length;
}

function addEntry(string cloudID, address gatewayID, string spID, string spMetadata, string scMetaAttr) public returns (uint)
{
require(msg.sender==gatewayID);
var sls = ServiceListStruct(cloudID, gatewayID, spID, spMetadata, scMetaAttr);
BCServiceList.push(sls);
return 1;
}

function deleteEntry(string cloudID, address gatewayID, string spID, string spMetadata, string scMetaAttr) public returns (uint)
{
require(msg.sender==gatewayID);
int pos = -1;
for(uint index = 0; index< BCServiceList.length; index++)
{
  if(compareStrings(cloudID, BCServiceList[index]._cloudID))
  {
    if(gatewayID == BCServiceList[index]._gatewayID)
    {
      if(compareStrings(spID, BCServiceList[index]._serviceProducerID))
      {
        if(compareStrings(spMetadata, BCServiceList[index]._serviceProducerMetadata))
        {
          if(compareStrings(scMetaAttr, BCServiceList[index]._serviceConsumerMetaAttr))
          {
            pos = int(index);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
if(pos > -1)
{
  for(uint i = uint(pos); i < BCServiceList.length -1 ; i++)
  {
    BCServiceList[i] = BCServiceList[i+1];
    delete BCServiceList[BCServiceList.length-1];
    BCServiceList.length--;
  }
return 1;
}
else
return 0;
}

function compareStrings(string s1, string s2) internal returns(bool)
{
var slice1 = s1.toSlice();
var slice2 = s2.toSlice();
var result = slice1.compare(slice2);
if(result == 0)
return true;
else
return false;
}
}
```

And I tried to test it using Remix IDE and it works as expected.

> 1. tried to add a service from an account other than the one deployed the contract and deleted the service entry using the same account and it worked.
> 2. tried to add service from one account and deleted from other account and the require statement failed as expected

But, when I try to test it using truffle, it fails. The test file is as follows:

```
const PublishService = artifacts.require('PublishService');
contract('PublishService', function(accounts) {
  it("addEntry function call from a valid account", function() {
    return PublishService.new({from: accounts[0]}).then(instance => { return instance.addEntry.call("LC1","0xca6e598bac8319860c663926f98096fdb279e55e", "LC1SP1", "SP1MD", "SC_ATTR",{"from": accounts[1]}); }).then(result => {
      assert.equal(result, 1, "[E] addEntry function test failed");
    });
  });
  it("deleteEntry function call from a valid account", function() {
    return PublishService.new({from: accounts[0]}).then(instance => { return instance.deleteEntry.call("LC1","0xca6e598bac8319860c663926f98096fdb279e55e", "LC1SP1", "SP1MD", "SC_ATTR",{"from": accounts[1]}); }).then(result => {
      assert.equal(result, 1, "[E] deleteEntry function test failed");
    });
  });

});
```

The second parameter of the call function is the account[1](https://github.com/Arachnid/solidity-stringutils/blob/master/strings.sol) id from the testrpc network
Here is the result of it.

[image]

The addEntry function succeeds but the `deleteEntry` failed. I can't figure out the reason. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are trying to compare a Bignumber object coming from a transaction call in web3 with a number literal

```
assert.equal(result, 1, "[E] deleteEntry function test failed");
```

You probably should use

```
result.toNumber()
```

instead of

```
result
```

when comparing with JS integers.

See this question and answer to elaborate on BigNumber methods.

[What are *C*, *E* and *S* properties in message call return object?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/what-are-c-e-and-s-properties-in-message-call-return-object)

Comment: I am returning either 0 or 1  in the deleteEntry function as shown in above piece of code