# How to unit test struct values

Tags: solidity, truffle, blockchain, truffle-contract, truffle-test

I'm new to Solidity development and I'm trying to figure out the best way to test a function which sets the values of a struct in my Truffle environment.

Firstly, is it expected that the result of the promise returns in the format below:

`[ BigNumber { s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 5 ] }, 'John' ]`

And if so is this the correct pattern to test the correct property has been set by the setter method (in this case name: John):  `assert.equal(res[1], "John");`

See below for the example contract I'm attempting to test:

**./contracts/Adoption.sol:**

```
contract Adoption {

struct Dog {
    uint age;
    string name;
}

Dog[] public dogs;

function createDog(uint _age, string _name) public {
    dogs.push(Dog(_age, _name)) - 1;
}
```

}

**./test/Adoption.js**

```
return Adoption.deployed()
  .then(function(instance) {
    instance.createDog(5, "John");
    return instance.dogs(0);
  })
  .then(function(res) {
    // dog age should equal 5
    assert.equal(res[0], 5);
    // dog name should equal John
    assert.equal(res[1], "John");
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately structures were not part of the original solidity [ABI specification](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/abi-spec.html) so they will return instead a tuple of values.

Another problem is that javascript doesn't support integer with sufficient precision. To avoid problems like losing precision or rounding errors web3 will wrap integers to objects `BigNumber`, see [What are *C*, *E* and *S* properties in message call return object?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/what-are-c-e-and-s-properties-in-message-call-return-object) for other details.

To compare `BigNumber`s you can convert them to ordinary javascripts numbers with `.toNumber()` (this will only work for small integers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin), for large numbers probably is best to convert to string or use some of the methods from `BigNumber` library.

```
return Adoption.deployed()
  .then(function(instance) {
    instance.createDog(5, "John");
    return instance.dogs(0);
  })
  .then(function(res) {
    // dog age should equal 5
    assert.equal(res[0].toNumber(), 5);
    // dog name should equal John
    assert.equal(res[1], "John");
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can deconstruct a struct's values when doing unit tests in Hardhat. In your example, if you would like to get the age and name from a struct then the code would be:

let [age, name] = contractInstance.dogs()

The id would be the position of the dog that you would like. Then you should be able to compare the age or name variables to your input as usual.